# Avoid CSS styling between certain adjacent elements and classes

Tags: css, r-markdown, knitr, padding, html-heading

I would like to add `padding-top: 20px;` between `h3` and `body` but not if `h3` is preceded by another element (e.g., `h2`). Is this possible?

Adding `padding-top` to all headings gives the desired padding when a heading is preceded by body text but an undesired padding between headlines:

[image]

Note that this document is Rmarkdown created using `knitr`, so I don't have full control over all the html. A pure CSS-solution would be preferred.

---

UPDATE:
To anyone also using `knitr` for Rmarkdown, the solution turned out to be a rather complex targeting:

```
/* First h2 following h1 */
.level1 > .level2:nth-child(3) > h2 {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
/* First h3 following h2 */
.level2 > .level3:nth-child(3) > h3 {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Looking at the generated HTML, I learned that the first `h2` after a `h1` was in the third element in `level1` and that that element was called `level2`. Similarly for the first `h3`. This is what is targeted above. The structure is probably different in other documents so take a look yourself.

Comment: have a look at css selectors in w3schools.com for more ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `>` selector plus `:first-child` to target only a direct `h3` child.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.test {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.test > h3:first-child { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h3>Targeted h3</h3>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <h3>h3 not targeted</h3>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <h3>h3 not targeted because of the p tag</h3>
  <h3>h3 not targeted</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It turned out that the correct solution in my case was more complicated, `.level2 > .level3:nth-child(3) > h3`, but I wouldn't have figured it out without these answers pointing to the selector `>` and `:first-child`. Your answer was particularly instructive to that effect.

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
body > h3:first-child {
   padding-top: 20px;
}
```

That will affect only immediate child of body with a header3, with nothing in between.

Thanks to @Oram, for pointing out missing :first-child

Comment: No. It will not work, because it means that h3 is a direct child. Not that it doesn't have a sibling h2 before it.

Comment: That depends from the html, without seeing more it's hard to tell if it'll work.

The wanted layout could be body h3 and the unwanted layout body h2+h3

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
body > h3:first-child {
   padding-top: 20px;
}
```

It will only apply the CSS to the first direct child of the body which is a h3.